# Component doesn't get serialized

Tags: c#, serialization, custom-controls, design-time

I create a control with a property with type of (DataGridViewColumnColection). 
For setting this component at design time, I create a custom designer. At design time every thing is ok. I can create columns, change details and so on but at run time all of my setting will disappear. I guess that problem is in the code serialization. My setting dosen't get serialized in initializecomponent method.

You can download some parts of my project from here:

http://rapidshare.com/files/452543887/Training.zip

In student form properties you can see a property(MasterColumns),
this property controls datagridview columns at design time correctly, but in run time...
you can see..
Please Help Me

Comment: you can download project from hear:http://rapidshare.com/files/452543887/Training.zip - in student form i have a property (MasterColumns) that control columns of datagridview in designtime correctly but in run time... you can see...

Comment: You'll get a better response if you post code in your question, rather than asking people download some .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute.  Here is a C++ example :-

```
private: int fullWidth;
    public:
        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility::Visible)]
        property int FullWidth
        {
            int get() { return this->fullWidth; }
            void set(int width) {
                this->fullWidth = width;
            }
        }
```